# my videos on google bucket can not fast forward or rewind

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So i built an e-learning platform with node.js and vue.js, and i am using GCP buckets to store my videos privately, everything works perfectly asides the fact that my videos can not fast forward or rewind, if you try moving the video to a specific position (maybe towards the end of the video) it returns to the same spot where you were initially, at first i taught it was a vue problem, but i tried playing this videos from my GCP bucket dashboard directly but it does the same thing. it only works fine when i use the firefox browser.
i am using the Uniform: No object-level ACLs enabled access control and the Not public permission settings. I am new the GCP, i have no idea what could be the problem
here is the node.js function i am using

```
const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.file) {
            res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
            return;
        }
        
        const gcsFileName = `${Date.now()}-${req.file.originalname}`;
        var reader = fs.createReadStream('uploads/'+req.file.originalname);
        reader.pipe(
            bucket.file(gcsFileName).createWriteStream({ resumable: false, gzip: true })
                .on('finish', () => {
                    // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
                    const publicUrl = format(
                        `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/` + gcsFileName
                    );
                    // console.log('https://storage.googleapis.com/faslearn_files/' + gcsFileName)
                    fs.unlink('uploads/' + req.file.originalname, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("failed to delete local image:" + err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('successfully deleted local image');
                        }
                    });


                    res.status(200).send(publicUrl);
                })
                .on('error', err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    return
                })
                //.end(req.file.buffer)
        )
        // Read and display the file data on console
        reader.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('seen chunk');
        });


    } catch (err) {
        console.log(" some where");
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It may not be the GCP but the encoding of the video that you are using, can you share the encoding type of the video here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was comming from the way i encoded the video, i was supposed to use the blob but i used the pipe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).